# How does this show non-uniqueness?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

From Kresyzig's Functional Analysis:

> Define the operator $T^*$ between two Hilbert spaces as the operator such that $\langle Tx, y \rangle = \langle x, T^* y \rangle$ where $T$ is an operator.
>
> If order that $T^*$ be an operator for each $y$ which is supposed to belong to the domain $D(T^*)$ of $T^*$ the corresponding $y^* = T^*y$ must be unique.  We claim this holds if and only if: $D(T)$ is dense in $H$.
>
> Indeed, if $D(T)$ is not dense in $H$, then $\overline{D(T)} \ne H$, the orthogonal complement of $\overline{D(T)}$ in $H$ contains a nonzero $y_1$ and $y_1 \perp x$ for every $x \in D(T)$, that is, $\langle x, y_1 \rangle = 0$.  But then we obtain $\langle x, y^* \rangle = \langle x, y^* \rangle + \langle x, y_1 \rangle = \langle x, y^* + y_1 \rangle$, which shows non-uniqueness.

Can someone explain how this shows non-uniqueness? How does $\langle x, y^* \rangle = \langle x, y^* \rangle + \langle x, y_1 \rangle = \langle x, y^* + y_1 \rangle$ imply that there's not a unique $y^*$ such that $T^* y = y^*$?

Comment: Where exactly in Kresyzig is that from? I cannot seem to find the passage.

Comment: It is in section $10.1$ after the first theorem.  "Unbounded Linear Operators and their Hilbert-Adjoint Operators" is the chapter title.

Answer (score 2):

The element $y^{\ast} \in H$ is defined by the fact that $\forall x \in H: \langle Tx, y \rangle = \langle x, y^{\ast}\rangle$. So given that $D(T)$ is not dense, we want to show that there exist $y \neq z$ s.t. $\forall x \in H: \langle x, y\rangle = \langle x, z\rangle$. With $z:= y^{\ast} + y_1$ this is precisely what is given.

In other words we have $T^{\ast} y = y^{\ast} = y^{\ast} + y_1$, but $y^{\ast} \neq y^{\ast} + y_1$, which shows that for any $y \in H$ the corresponding $T^{\ast}y$ is not unique.

Note that this relies crucially on the fact that there exists a non-zero element $y_1 \in H$ s.t. $\langle x, y_1 \rangle = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$T^*$ sends $y$ to $y^*$ by definition. But it also sends $y$ to $y^*+y_1$ because for all $x\in D(T),$

$\langle x, y^*+y_1 \rangle=\langle x, y^*\rangle+\langle x,y_1\rangle=\langle x,y^*\rangle=\langle Tx,y\rangle.$